# How to give edit access to a field to some user roles and some user role have read access?

Tags: page-layout, permission-sets, admin

How to give only two users with different  roles the ability to modify some fields but others should have read only access?
I dont want to create different page layout but created two permission set where for one edit access has been provided and for other only read access but for both the profile edit access is coming only. Not able to understand why read access is not working.

Comment: Field access only enable via Permission set and Profiles only in Salesforce. Please check his other assigned `Permission sets`/ `Profile` accidently enable the `Edit` access for the Read Only Permission set users.

Comment: Did you assign those permission sets to the relevant users? What does the FLS look like for your target SObject? Permissions are additive, you can't take away permissions that someone is already granted (with one main exception that doesn't apply here).